# Case statement with dimension in MDX Query

Tags: reporting-services, mdx

In a MDX query I am using with case statement in SSRS Report. It is not returning the desired result. It should filter `[Facility Market]` based on the selection of the  `Territory` parameter.

```
with member [Dim Facility].[Facility Market].[Facility Market] as
case  [Dim North Texas Sales].[North Texas Rural Sales Territory].currentmember

when   [Dim North Texas Sales].[North Texas Rural Sales Territory].&[NTXSalesRuralEast] then [Dim Facility].[Facility Market].&[OKLAHOMA] 

end

select......
```

I would like to change the value of facility market dimension based on the parameter selection and filter the dataset based on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Case statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144841.aspx) only work with scalar values.

You should rather use an expression like this one:

```
IIf([Dim North Texas Sales].[North Texas Rural Sales Territory].CurrentMember IS [Dim North Texas Sales].[North Texas Rural Sales Territory].&[NTXSalesRuralEast],
[Dim Facility].[Facility Market].&[OKLAHOMA],
...)
```

Comment: Does it matter if parameter has space in the value like "ABC East"?

Comment: The parameter can have a space, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145572

Answer (score 0):

```
with member [Dim Facility].[Facility Market].[Facility Market] as
case  

when  [Dim North Texas Sales].[North Texas Rural Sales Territory].currentmember IS [Dim North Texas Sales].[North Texas Rural Sales Territory].&[NTXSalesRuralEast] then [Dim Facility].[Facility Market].&[OKLAHOMA] 

end

select......
```